# What does "*", "**", and "***" mean in Timeshift filters?

Tags: backup, syntax

When excluding a folder, Timeshift generates a filter rule of this format:

```
/home/nils/.cache/***
```

What do the three stars mean? And what do two or a single star mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeshift uses `rsync`.  The pattern you show is an `rsync` pattern that matches the directory `/home/nils/.cache` as well as anything below it.

It is slightly different from `/home/nils/.cache/**` which matches the directory's contents (at any level below the `.cache` directory), but which does not match the directory itself.

In the `rsync` manual, the varying number of stars at the end of a filter rule is described like this:

> a `*` matches zero or more non-slash characters.

> a `**` matches zero or more characters, including slashes.

> a trailing `***` in the pattern is a shorthand that allows
> you to match a directory and all its contents using a
> single rule.  For example, specifying `dir_name/***` will
> match both the `dir_name` directory (as if `dir_name/` had
> been specified) and everything in the directory (as if
> `dir_name/**` had been specified).

Summarising the above, one may say that `*` matches any name in a directory, `**` matches any name in *or beneath* a directory, and `***` matches any name in or beneath a directory as well as the directory itself.